# capistrano error msg: Please install the pg adapter: `gem install activerecord-pg-adapter` (cannot load such file --

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, capistrano, bundler

I am using capistrano and get this error message:

```
Please install the pg adapter: `gem install activerecord-pg-adapter` (cannot load such file -- active_record/connection_adapters/pg_adapter)
```

I have removed the gem 'pg' from my Gemfile and `bundle install`d . I don't see the pg gem in my Gemfile.lock. I have also changed my production db to a sqlite3 adapter. Why is Rails 3.2 / Capistrano / Bundler asking for this? I'm not using it and not in Gemfile.lock and how do I resolve it? I am using ubuntu 12.04 on server that this is happening on.

thx in advance

Also, when I run what it tells me to run, I get:

```
deploy@oahu:~$ gem install activerecord-pg-adapter
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'activerecord-pg-adapter' (>= 0) in any repository
^CERROR:  Interrupted
deploy@oahu:~$ \
```

** edit 1 **

from root of app

```
Fri Mar 22$ grep -ri 'pg-adapter' *
Fri Mar 22$
```

database.yml

```
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/production.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

here's a screenshot of the database.yml file on github:

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check your `database.yml`. You probably have an entry in it called `pg-adapter`, when the correct adapter for Postgres is `postgresql`. If you remove or replace that, this should work.

Comment: thx, I have added my database.yml and done the results of a grep through the directory tree. I'm pretty baffled. Any other thoughts? thx again - I know prob something stupid on my part

Comment: You say this happens during a deploy -- is a different `database.yml` copied to your config directory during the deploy process?

Comment: hmm... I don't think so. Using capistrano; I don't know how a different database.yml could get there. Checked on github and no reference to pg in database.yml. I suspect you're right but I'm thinking how this could be. Capistrano deletes the release; let me see if I can get it to not delete release

Comment: just added a screenshot of the database.yml on github - see no reference to postgres