# How to use old gem versions with ruby?

Tags: ruby, postgresql, pg

Gem info - ruby 1.8.7, pg 0.9.0, postgres 0.8.1
All super old gems. I can't change that.

Code -

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'active_record'
require 'pg'
require 'postgres'

conn = PGconn.connect(:host => 'db.com', :port => 1234, :username => 'db1', :password => 'db1')
conn = PGconn.open
res = conn.exec("select * from a;")
PGconn.close
```

Require postgres line causes the following message and does not allow the code to execute. How do I make it work ? The warning is given below:

```
This is an old, deprecated version of the Ruby PostgreSQL driver that hasn't
been maintained or supported since early 2008.

You should install/require 'pg' instead.

If you need the 'postgres' gem for legacy code that can't be converted, you can
still install it using an explicit version, like so:

  gem install postgres -v '0.7.9.2008.01.28'
  gem uninstall postgres -v '>0.7.9.2008.01.28'

If you have any questions, the nice folks in the Google group can help:

  http://goo.gl/OjOPP / ruby-pg@googlegroups.com
```

Comment: Not much helpful info here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1664364/how-to-handle-ruby-on-rails-error-please-install-the-postgresql-adapter-gem or here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15582618/capistrano-error-msg-please-install-the-pg-adapter-gem-install-activerecord-p
Still stuck!!!

Comment: Well, it says 'You should install/require 'pg' instead.'. Do you actually need the gem? I have Postgres running and only use the pg gem.

Comment: @elactic - I have pg, postgres and active record. checked it using `gem list` command

Comment: Is this in a script or something?  Did you do what the warning message said to do?  Uninstall the new `postgres` gem.  You likely have a "current" (`0.8+`) version installed which has this warning.  You may want to [use bundler](http://bundler.io) to get the right version of the gem you're needing instead of just relying on what's installed.

Comment: @NickVeys - Yes, i did whatever the script told me to do. I have the pg gem, but its too old to work with all the online examples from google search. In old postgres, you used PGconn to make db conn. With new, you use PG class. PGconn won't work because the gem it comes from is deprecated. And all my gems come from bundler which points to our repo of dusty old gems.

Comment: Are you using bundler in your script to ensure you get the right gem version?  Having a Gemfile doesn't mean you are using bundler necessarily. You can specify one that isn't deprecated and use it. Otherwise you'll just get (I think) the most recent one upon require.